# Object complement adjective, or direct object, or?

Tags: adjectives, objects, complements, direct-objects

> Jill painted the kitchen rosey red.

In this sentence, would *red* be considered an object complement adjective?  If so, what do I do with *rosey*, since I cannot have an adjective modifying another adjective?  I think it is a stretch to say that *rosey* is an adverb modifying *red*, answering the question, "What degree red?"

Is this actually a `S-Vt-IO-DO`?  Something substantive (*red*) is being applied to/for the kitchen. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: I would say that _rosey_ is clearly an adverb here, though not a degree one. Compare with _bright red_ or _deep red_. As for the function of _rosey red_ on phrasal level, I'm wondering if it could be an adjunct. It is optional (_Jill painted the kitchen_) and further specifies _painted_ (answering the question _Painted how?_). I don't think traditional grammar works well with sentences like that!

Comment: Who says you can't have an adjective modifying another adjective? In English almost any adjective can be used as an adverb in a compound adjective like "rosy red" or "deep purple". And what difference does is make what it's called? For the record, _red_ in this sentence is an adjective that comes from the underlying meaning: _Jill caused the kitchen to become rosey red by painting (it)._ English has many special verbs for causing things to have specific properties by various methods: _Jill pried the can open; Jill knocked Max unconscious; Jill shot her attacker dead;_ etc.

Comment: Yes, sure: it doesn't matter how you call it as long as you allow adjective/adjective modification. If you don't, then it would act as an adverb, though.

Comment: If a determiner is added, "Jill painted the kitchen a rosy red," does that cause "red" to act as a substantive adjective which can be modified by an adjective?  If so, do I then have a S-Vt-IO-DO pattern?  If this is the case, maybe I have an implied determiner.  It seems as though "red" is acting as a noun in the original sentence, and I know that it cannot be an object complement noun.  Red is not the same thing as the kitchen.  Anymore thoughts?

Comment: This is actually one of those causatives, which have something of the appearance of a bitransitive verb, but are not usually construed to be such.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95032 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/74536

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you sure about all that? I always feel like “deep purple” is making the color act more like a noun, even if you did have a “deep purple jacket”. But you can’t have a “deep loud boy” or a “funny ready attendant” or a “really big different idea” where the first of the adjectives applies to the second one and not to the noun. See? The colors really do seem different from other adjectives here.

Comment: It's just that color terms often have orthogonal scales. _Deep_ is a metaphor for little light, which is coherent with purple, at the end of the EM spectrum. There's no _deep yellow_, though,  nor  _bright purple_, as fixed phrases, though they're compositional, and they might even be useful descriptions in specialized or metaphoric uses (for cowardice or xenon, respectively).

Comment: You could use similar verbs with this pattern.  I dyed my hair flaming red.  She colored her wool dusty gray.  This type of sentence is commonly used as an example of a S-Vt-DO-OCA pattern.  What do you do with the modifiers, "flaming" and "dusty"?  These sentences seem to be asking for a determiner between the object and "flaming red" or "dusty gray".  If one does insert an "a", I would assume "red" or "gray" to be acting as a noun (substantive adjective) and diagram the sentence as a S-Vt-IO-DO.  Is this also the pattern of the original sentence, "Jill painted the kitchen {a} rosey red."?

Comment: Could you replace "red" with another adjective such as "bright"?  "Lori painted the kitchen bright."  This sounds unfinished.  I want to add, " {a} bright{er} {color}".

Comment: @Oliver Mason You state that rosy is an adverb, though not a degree one.  What adverb question would it answer (how, why, where, when, how much, how often, to what extent, under what conditions)?  I really appreciate the feedback.  I need to teach the object complement adjectives to a group of fourth graders on Wednesday, and I do not want to pass on faulty information.

Comment: @tboz In this case _rosy_ describes the quality of _red_; I'm not sure that you can say it answers a specific adverb question. Maybe at a stretch it would be the _how_ one? _How red? Rosy red (rather than deep red)_. But I'm not quite sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "rosey" is definitely an adverb, and modifies the type of red.

Answer (score 0):

"Rosy" and "red" are both adjectives, with an elided noun:

> Jill painted the kitchen a rosy red [color].

Comment: I would disagree: you cannot say _Jill painted the kitchen a red ros(e)y_ (but _a reddish pink_ would be possible), so they are clearly not on the same level. Though _rosy_ itself can of course be used as an adjective. In your example you have added a determiner which would suggest an elision, but that is not in the original sentence.

Comment: Yes, an adjective can modify an adjective.  But often the order matters.  You can, after all, say, "Jill painted the kitchen a red rosy color."  Here they are clearly both adjectives.  "Elided," by the way, indicates a missing word in the original sentence.

Comment: Would "red" then be diagrammed as an object complement adjective?  How would you diagram "rosy"?

Comment: Sure, I know what 'elision' means. But from your example I assume you refer to _color_ as being elided, which only really works since you inserted _a_, which was not in the original sentence. If it had been _Jill painted the kitchen **a** rosey red_ then there would be an obvious elision, but not so without the _a_.

Comment: There's no question that "rosy" modifies "red." It doesn't have to designate degree to be an adverb here. It denotes a particular shade/tint. I would accept it as either adverb or adjective in this position, but I wouldn't agree with reconstructing the sentence (the elided noun argument) to justify this usage; that's not necessary.

Comment: ... There's no question that "rosy" modifies "red." Agreed. I'd use the more modern suggested classification 'adjective modifier' here because that's what it's being used to do.

Answer (score 0):

*Rosey* is an adjective that modifies the adjective red which is used as a noun in this case. Adjectives can often be used as nouns and modified by another adjective, e.g.

> No shelter for the unfortunate homeless!